# Trying to load a new scene when I enter a cube in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this code to enter a new scene:

```
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;
// add this line to use the SceneManagment library
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private string loadLevel;

    void onTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene (loadLevel);
        }

    }

}
```

I then add this script to the cube and select it a trigger. I then type in the scene that I want it to send me too, but when i walk into it nothing happens at all. I have tried different variations but it just doesnt seem to work.

My character that I am using is a unity asset called man in suit but I have selected its tag as "Player". Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Does `other` game object have a `Collider` component attached to it ?

Comment: First thing I notice  `onTriggerEnter` should change to `OnTriggerEnter`

Comment: @Aybe as in my player? I’m not sure. How do I check? (Sorry very new to unity)

Comment: @JamesRees if you click the player you look at the inspector and see if it has a collider

Comment: You should also verify that the scene you are trying to load is in the building settings.

Comment: @Eddge yes it is in building settings

Comment: There is a pretty good answer below, check it out.

Comment: I suggest Loading the scenes by their index in the Build Settings > Scenes in build, it is more explicit and less error prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Handler for your trigger won't be invoked

As [Sunimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5033630/sunimal-s-k-malkakulage) allready noted you need to fix the typo.

```
  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (loadLevel);
    }
}
```

### Ensure your Scene is included and checked in the Build Settings

As you can see in the Screenshot below i have added a SampleScene to my build settings. There are 2 ways of adding scenes into the build

1. By clicking "Add Open Scenes" you can add the scene which is
   currently open to that list.
2. Drag & Drop the scene from your ProjectView into the List

[image: Screenshot of the build settings]

### Ensure your SceneName is set correctly

Your loadLevel field would in my case need to have the value "Scenes/SampleScene".

```
 [SerializeField] private string loadLevel;
```

### The player needs a collider

As you use the OnTriggerEnter method, your Player object needs to have some sort of Collider attached to it. This can be a BoxCollider, SphereCollider or some other Collider. <strike>Note that the "Is Trigger" checkbox needs to be checked. Else it won't act as trigger.</strike>

**Edit:** Thanks [Eddge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2434628/eddge) for correcting me. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49180581/4992212) answer for a deeper explanation about Triggers.

[image: image of collider component]

### Programatically ensure you have a BoxCollider component beside your LoadScenes component

You can add the [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) Attribute at your class. It basically ensures you have the given type added as a component. This will also automatically add a box collider to an object, when you add this script.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {
/// your other code is here
}
```

Thanks to [Sunimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5033630/sunimal-s-k-malkakulage) for this hint!

### What if that did not solve the problem?

If all this does not help, please provide an screenshot of the inspector of your Playerobject. That way we can see what components are attached to that object and how they are "configured"

Comment: This is a complete answer. One simple addition we can add `[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {
`  will automaticaly add components to the game object

Comment: Good idea! I add this

Comment: The player does not need a collider that is a trigger(just a collider).  In order for OnTriggerEnter to be called both objects need a collider, 1 of them has to be a trigger, and one has to have a rigidbody.  This is per the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Have my upvote for the good explanation of Triggers :) I tried to correct that mistake in the answer

Answer (score 1):

### SceneManagement

To use the SceneManager to load a scene you must ensure that your scene is in the build settings, per Tobias's answer.

### Triggers

In all software development case does matter and it is incredibly important.  `OnTriggerEnter` is not the same as `onTriggerEnter`, also note `OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)` is not the same as `OnTriggerEnter(Collision col)`

In order to use any of the trigger methods there are 3 things that are a must:

1. Both Objects have to have colliders.
2. One of the colliders have to be marked as a trigger.
3. One of the objects have to have a rigidbody.

The trigger event is sent to the object with the rigidbody and whatever object is the trigger, in the circumstance that both objects are triggers both will receive it.